# Is it possible to setup WebStorm to open just one Chrome profile?

Tags: google-chrome, webstorm

I have several Chrome profiles. Is it possible to setup WebStorm to open exact one? (for example for debug)

**UPD**:

- tried to go `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Web Browsers`
  and [setup command line](https://superuser.com/a/377195/473228) there. Still does not work
- custom profile directory also did not help.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Web Browsers" -- if you select Chrome entry and click on `edit` button you will be able to provide any command line parameters as well as specify custom profile directory. In theory this should do it (never did like that myself -- that's why "in theory").

Comment: thank you for the hint! still did not make it work: neither with command line options(took from here - http://superuser.com/a/377195/473228) nor with custom director profile

Comment: 1) Where do you use it (JS debug/etc)? 2) Do you have JetBrains extension installed there? 3) If a Chrome with JetBrains extension is already running, then it will be reused instead of launching new one. So try with disabling that extension in unwanted profiles.

Comment: Other than that I have found these tickets whihc may be related: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4434 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16489

Comment: disabling JetBrains extension helped! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Web Browsers`
2. Select desired Chrome entry (in case if you have more than one) and click on `edit` button
3. Now you can provide command line parameters as well as specify custom profile directory.

---

Please note: if Chrome with JetBrains extension is already running then it will be reused instead of launching new one.

Solution: disable JetBrains extension in unwanted profile (e.g. the one that you use for your normal web browsing).

Other than that (related tickets):

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4434
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16489